# calculating cohort data in firebase -> bigquery, but I want to separate them by tracking source. Grouping wont work?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate quality of users with cohort data in bigquery
My current query is:

```
WITH analytics_data AS (
    SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_timestamp, event_name, app_info.id,geo.country as country,platform  ,app_info.id as bundle_id,
      UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP("2019-12-05 00:00:00")) AS start_day,
      3600*1000*1000*24 AS one_day_micros
    FROM `table.events_*`
    WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN "20191205" AND "20191218"
  )
  SELECT day_7_cohort / day_0_cohort AS seven_day_conversion FROM (
      WITH day_7_users AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
        FROM analytics_data
        WHERE event_name = 'watched_20_ads' AND event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(12*one_day_micros) 
      ), day_0_users AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
      FROM analytics_data
      WHERE event_name = "first_open"
        AND bundle_id = "com.bundle.id" 
        AND country = "United States"
        AND platform = "ANDROID"
        AND event_timestamp BETWEEN start_day AND start_day+(1*one_day_micros)
    )
    SELECT 
      (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM day_0_users) AS day_0_cohort,(SELECT count(*) 
       FROM day_7_users 
       JOIN day_0_users USING (user_pseudo_id)) AS day_7_cohort
)
```

the problem is that I'm unable to separate the users by tracking source.
I want to separate the users by: tracking source and country.

What I'm curently getting:
[image: more]
what I would like to see:

[image]

What would be perfect:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's possible to write a query that would return the data in a single table, without involving more queries and data storage elsewhere.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  Your explanation is not clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added more context

Comment: Do you care about a user only being counted in 1 source/country combo?  Basically, do you want their first source/country combo to define their 'cohort'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your question is missing some data/fields, but I will provide a 'general' solution.

```
with data as (
  -- Select the fields you need to define criteria and cohorts
),
cohort_info as (
  -- Cohort Logic (might be more complicated than this)
  select user_id, source, country---, etc...
  from data
  group by 1,2,3
),
day_0_users as (
  -- Logic to determine who you are measuring for your calculation
),
day_7_users as (
  -- Logic to detemine who qualifies as a 7 day user for your calculation
),
joined as (
  -- Join your CTEs together
  select
    cohort_info.source,
    cohort_info.country,
    count(distinct day_0_users.user_id) as day_0_count,
    count(distinct day_7_users.user_id) as day_7_count
  from day_0_users
  left join day_7_users using(user_id)
  inner join cohort_info using(user_id)
  group by 1,2
)
select *, day_7_count/day_0_count as seven_day_conversion
from joined
```

I think using several CTEs in this manner will make your code more readable and will enable you to track your logic a bit better.  Nested Subqueries tend to get ugly.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try running something similar and I'll get back to you on how it goes

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but your solution was what I was looking for, thank you, worked wonderfully :)